# How to generate fake data from array in special order

Tags: laravel, faker

I would like to generate 48 rows (every year with 12 month no repeat) of fake data records in the special order like this...

```
dataYear  dataMonth  monthlyRevenue accumulatedRevenue
2015         Jan          123456            123456
2015         Feb          123456            123456
2015         Mar          123456            123456
2015         Apr          123456            123456
2015         May          123456            123456
...
```

Below is my code,  is there anyone knows how to do it through Laravel - Fake?

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Model\gamingdata::class, function (Faker $faker) {
$dataMonth = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
$year = [2015,2016,2017,2018];    
static $order1 = 0;
static $order2 = 0;

$order1 = $order1++;
$order2 = $order2++;
return [
    'dataYear' => $year[$order1],
    'dataMonth' => $dataMonth[$order2],
    'monthlyRevenue' => $faker->numberBetween(100000, 9000000),
    'accumulatedRevenue' => $faker->numberBetween(100000, 9000000),
];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried @Lim Kean Phang's opinion edit the demand directly in seeder but not in Factor php and it works...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Model\gamingdata;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class GamingDataTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    DB::table('gamingdatas')->delete();
    $year = 2014;
    $dataMonth=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    for ( $i=0; $i <4; $i++ ) 
    {
      $year= $year+ 1;
        for ( $j=0; $j <12; $j++ )
        {
        DB::table('gamingdatas')->insert([
            'dataYear' => $year,
            'dataMonth' => $dataMonth[$j],
            'monthlyRevenue' =>  rand(1000,10000),
            'accumulatedRevenue' =>  rand(1000,10000),
        ]);
        };
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy data usually created by Seeder (php artisan make:seeder DummyData).Can i be something like this?

```
$year = 2015
$dataMonth=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
for(i=0,i <23,i++){     
DB::table('table_name')->insert([
            'dateYear' => $year= $year+i,
            'dateMonth' => $dataMonth,
            'monthlyRevenue' =>  rand(1000,10000),
            'accumulatedRevenue' =>  rand(1000,10000),
        ]);i++}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I never think about try to insert it in the seeder...
Your comment does help me a lot!

Comment: Glad it helps,there still more to explore and learn in Laravel even for me. Cheers! @WKenny

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage faker to put the data directly into the DB for you a little more elegantly like this:

```php
factory(App\Model\gamingdata::class)->create([
    'dataYear' => $year,
    'dataMonth' => $month
]);
```

You'll have to iterate over the months as shown above, but this should give you a good start.  You can also pass a number as the second attribute to the factory helper function to indicate how many records you'd like to insert.  See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing) for more details.  Examples can be found a little over half way down the document.

Comment: thanks for your reply~ I tired before but it doesn't work...
factory php can't use loop to input the variables
maybe I just don't know how to write it